# Google Earth Map Plugin not works in desktop application

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I developed a web page, which displays a google earth map and hosted in an  iis server.  Now, I want to invoke that page in a browser control through a vb.net desktop application.
When i run the application, the browser control shows 'Your browser does not support the Google Earth Plugin'. But, at the same time, the web page is getting displayed in the chrome browser without any error in the client systems. Also, the desktop application works properly in the server system.

Kindly suggest what could be the reason for the plugin not works in desktop application.

Windows XP & 7
Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 m

Thanks
Sivakumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the webbrowser control is using the 64bit version of Internet Explorer, hence the GEPlugin wont work.

To fix this simply compile your vb.net desktop application to target 'x86' rather than 'anyCpu'.

Comment: As you said, I recompiled to x86. But it didn't solve the problem. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I think you would need to provide more information to help then. Which version of IE are you using on the machines that are not working? Does the page work in IE on the machines (outside your application)? Also, does IE have the default security settings, etc?

Comment: Thanks Fraser. sorry for the minimum information. Actually I was trying to display the web page in an application developed for AutoCAD. Because of this compilation issue, I created a separate desktop application for displaying the web page, which will refresh for every 1 seconds. although it is not a proper way, my problem is solved now. In the stand-alone desktop application, by default it is compiled in x86. But in AutoCAD VB.Net, it is giving some error for x86 compilation, which I could not resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked for me! Do you know how can I make my desktop application work exactly like Google earth? Such that it shows location names and allow me to search for countries?

Comment: @Faizan - sure,  check out this library I put together. https://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

Comment: @Fraser Thanks for your reply. I am actually trying to control Google Earth navigation using Kinect gestures. Should I use Google earth in WPF application or windows form? I need guidance on how to start.

Comment: @Faizan It would be quite trivial to use Microsoft.Kinect along with the library to control the earth navigation with gestures in either winforms or wpf.

Comment: @Fraser I had been doing research since last couple of 3 days. I have got cursor control using Kinect but it's not very smooth. I have seen samples for  Kinect Basic control that provide grip gestures but the documentation is very rare and I am not getting how to detect grip and fire an event based on that. Can you give a sample working code?

Comment: The comments are not the place for an extended discussion or to answer further questions on topics unrelated to the original question - if you are stuck with something to do with Kinect ask your own question on this site.